# Calculating Maximum Sized File

Tags: c, file, unix, system, inode

I was working on a homework problem and I need help understanding how to approach the problem. I can't seem to find any resources online regarding this. The question is:

> Suppose a UNIX disk block will hold 2048 disk addresses. What is the
>   maximum sized file using:
>
> - Direct pointer?
> - Single indirection?
> - Double indirection?
> - Triple-indirection?

How would I go about calculating such values? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm not too familiar with this problem area.  Would you get the same answer among all file systems?

Comment: How many bits are there in a word? How many disk addresses can those bits address? Do you get more disk addresses by using an indirection? How about two indirections? Simplify it. Use just 3 bits, 8 locations. How many disk addresses with 3 bits? How many with an additional level of indirection?

Comment: @Matt : I believe the constraint "a UNIX disk block will hold 2048 disk addresses" presumes a tree-structured block allocation map, and so is specific to families of file systems that are structured that way.  The question doesn't apply to extent-oriented FSes like XFS, for example.

Comment: @Jake Z:  I made my comment above assuming the professor was describing an abstract tree structure.  If you google around (or go to Wikipedia), you'll see Linux's `ext2` structure has a tree structure described similarly to this, but it isn't a pure tree.  Do you know if the professor had a particular filesystem in mind, or just a pure, abstract tree block index?

Comment: It's based on Linux! Thanks for your help btw. I think I may have solved it.